# Cirrus Scale old half height server RJ45 network device not available on Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: networking, server, arm

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 ARM on an old Cirrusscale server, and the network device handle for the primary RJ45 connector does not come up, so I cannot simply plug into the LAN I am on.  This is a Gigabyte product, possibly several years old.

I had something similar to a full height ARM box in the same batch and also a Gigabyte product.

The one other symptom is that both the above boxes have a bunch of square hold NIC ports that all seem to come up.  It could be the RJ45 is just left off, or that the ARM install was only tested in small installs like Raspberry rather than large ones like ThunderX with lots of NICs.  This has five NIC handles that do come up, so I wonder if it is made to handle a short list.  Or it could be this thing is somehow old with an RJ45 handle that is somehow unfamiliar to modern Ubuntu.

Comment: FWIW:  I added a small NIC to the riser to get around this, which was my solution that worked on the second server I mention that I installed a few weeks back.

Comment: I got this on a second one, so it looks like three cases makes it not a simple hardware failure, but a software omission.